# Skip rows in the primary table if value found in secondary table MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have this table (payments)

```
| id | amount | payment    | frequency |
|----|--------|------------|-----------|
| 1  | 100    | 2017-05-15 | 12        |
| 2  | 200    | 2017-05-15 | 12        |
| 3  | 300    | 2017-05-17 | 4         |
```

And this one (payments_log):

```
| id | payment_id | payment    |
|----|------------|------------|
| 1  | 1          | 2017-04-15 |
| 2  | 1          | 2017-05-15 |
| 3  | 2          | 2017-04-15 |
```

Here is my query:

```
 SELECT p.id, p.amount, p.date AS payment_date, pl.date 
 FROM payments AS p 
 LEFT JOIN payments_log AS pl ON pl.payment_id = p.id 
 WHERE p.frequency = 12 AND
 DATE_FORMAT(p.date,'%m-%d') IN ('06-15','07-15','08-15','09-15','10-15','11-15','12-15','01-15','02-15','03-15','04-15','05-15')
```

I only wants to returns records with the matched payment date but if there any record in the payments_log table with the current date then skip any record in the primary table:

```
| id | amount | payment    | frequency |
|----|--------|------------|-----------|
| 2  | 200    | 2017-05-15 | 12        |
```

The ID 2 is valid because match with the '04-15' date but the record ID 1 is not valid because there is a payment_log with the current date.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not including year in the comparison? Any specific reason?

Comment: This is a table for recurrent payments, so I need to compare the payment date against the future days. I already found the solution



     SELECT p.id, p.amount, p.date
     FROM payments AS p 
     WHERE p.frequency = 12 AND DATE_FORMAT(p.created_at,'%m-%d') IN ('06-15','07-15','08-15','09-15','10-15','11-15','12-15','01-15','02-15','03-15','04-15','05-15')
     AND id NOT IN ( SELECT payment_id FROM payments_log WHERE date = '2017-05-15' )